# Date format get changed in Java-Spring-Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My objective is quite simple. Store the current date in the Oracle Global Temporary table and display that on JavaScript page using Spring MVC and Hibernate as ORM.

Code I wrote is (please note that system time is "Sat Mar 29 11:29:44 EST 2014"):

```
public List<TmpClass> getData() {
        Integer sno = 1;

        /* Write query to save the data in the temporary table. Function calls getSession().save(..) */
        Date date = new Date();
        saveData(new TmpClass(sno, date));

        /* Retrieve the data from TmpClass class. Function calls getSession().queryObject("from TmpClass") */
        return retrieveData();
    }
```

**Configuration file**:
hibernate.cfg.xml at resource path:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.tesco.larc.forms.TmpGenUtil" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

-servlet.xml has

```
<!-- Data Source for Oracle -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate Session Factory Configuration -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myproject" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

TmpClass

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TMPTABLE")
    public class TmpClass {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "SNO")
        private Integer sno;

        @Column(name = "dcol1")
        private Date date;

//getter and setter methods omitted
```

Controller class, creates stores the output of above function in a Model.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayContacts(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("Data", contactService.getData());

    return "eInfoScreen";
}
```

JavaScript code is :

```
<c:forEach items="${Data}" var="list">
                <tr>
                    <td>${list.id}</td>
                    <td>${list.date}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

I am getting date as:

```
Sr BAR_DATE
1 **88-Mar-2014**
```

I am not able to figure out, why instead of 29-Mar-2014, it is showing as 88-Mar-2014.

Any help or pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of TmpClass and how are you mapping it?

Comment: @takteek - I have edited Question section with the definition of TmpClass and Hibernate mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like when you defined your date format you used `DD` which is day of year rather than `dd` for day of month.  (March 29th is the 88th day of the year.)

Comment: @Affe- You're right. I was using DD instead of dd in the Date's getter method. Have modified it and it worked.